# Grid Lines to keep objects level

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids, guides

I'm not even sure what this is called and no matter what I look up I cant find the right thing. I only noticed when it disappeared I feel like I hit a key or clicked something and no matter the restart wont come back.

It was just like snap to point or grid lines but id have these pink lines come up so I knew things were level across the page. So an object drawn on one side of the page and then the other object would have an extended pink line ( like the guide lines ) to line it up to the other object so they were level if that makes sense. It was also way easier to click and move things now suddenly I have to zoom in and make sure I'm clicking just the right spot on the object to actual select it and move. Makes things I need to do a lot slower. I know its not snap to point because I already have that clicked on, any help would be appreciated!

the image below would be an example, a line used to show up so i could easily line the two arrows up with each other now its gone. 
[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be looking for the `View → Smart Guides`, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and that's that.